# How to set height proportional to width according to device dpi in android

Tags: android, android-imageview, dpi

I would like to fix the height of imageview but according to different devices and dpi's.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgFood"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_no_img" />
```

As of now I fixed the height to 200dp, but I want to keep it ratio of 1:2 instead of fix size. I know android works on dp but I am unable to figure out how can i keep the ratio for all devices. Width will be match parent (fit device width) but height needs to be changed accordingly.

Any idea/suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set your height dynamically like this.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();

ll.getLayoutParams().height = width/2;
ll.getLayoutParams().width = width;
ll.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set height or width ratio of views inside `LinearLayout` using the [`layout_weight`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) property, for example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <View
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This will cause the inner `Views` of the `LinearLayout` to take one and two thirds of its width, respectively.

Otherwise, if you have to use a different layout, there is currently no way to do this in .xml files, and the option is to fall back to setting the size programmatically, like in Hussnain Azam's answer (you don't always have to call for size of the display though).